# Import small stream in Impala

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hadoop-streaming, impala

We are currently on a Big Data project.

The Big Data platform Hadoop Cloudera.

Input of our system we have a small flow of data, we collect via Kafka (approximately 80Mo/h continuously).

Then the messages are stored in HDFS to be queried via Impala.

Our client does not want to separate the hot data with the cold data. After 5 mins, the data must be accessible in the history data (cold data). We chose to have a single database.

To insert the data, we use the JDBC connector provided by Impala API (eg INSERT INTO ...).
we are aware that this is not the recommended solution, each Impala insertion creates a file (<10kb) in HDFS.

We seek a solution to insert a small stream in a Imapala base which avoids getting many small files. 
What solution we preconize?

Comment: If your looking for any Impala oriented solution, you may consider add HBase to your cluster (on top of HDFS) and use Impala to query HBase. If your client does not want to separate your "cold" data from the "hot" data, you could reserve all you HDFS to HBase to store all the data directly into HBase, and query HBase with Impala. It's not a very common use of HBase, but it's not usual to store hot and cold data into the same storage service either... Or, you could try to ingest with flume from Kafka directly into HDFS and append new data to your existing files to not generate too small files